# Server setup script for Redis, HAProxy and Node.js

Tags: node.js, bash, redis, haproxy

I wrote a pretty basic setup script that handles most of the setup for a Three-server solution. [The solution and setup file are available on GitHub](https://github.com/The-Quill/StackNews)

The three servers are Redis, HAProxy and Node / Cron.

All three options handle only solution specific stuff (not including installing the frameworks)

I felt like my usage of `select` statements was a little over the top, and newline as a constant seemed a little hacky, but nonetheless, it works.

```
n="
"
# From http://stackoverflow.com/a/246128
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
pass (){
    echo $1 | sha256sum | head -c 64
}

# Redis
redis (){
    ulimit -n 10032
    slave=false;
    echo "Enter the desired password for the Redis instance:"
    read -s password
    password=$(pass $password)
    echo "Is this a slave?"
    select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
        case $yn in
            Yes ) slave=1; break;;
            No ) slave=0; break;;
        esac
    done
    slave_text="";
    if [[ $slave -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo "Enter the Master IP address:"
        read master_ip
        echo "Enter the Redis Master password:"
        read -s master_password
        slave_text="slaveof $master_ip 6379
masterauth $master_password $n"
    fi
    echo "tcp-keepalive 60
port 6379
tcp-backlog 511
timeout 600
dir $DIR
supervised upstart
daemonize yes
#bind 127.0.0.1
maxmemory-policy noeviction
requirepass $password
$slave_text
" > "/etc/redis/redis.conf"
    echo "The password for Redis is $password"
    sudo service redis restart
}


# HAProxy
haproxy (){
    stats=1;
    stats_text="stats disable$n";
    echo "Please enter the IP address of the web server:"
    read initial_ip
    echo "Please enter the port of the web server:"
    read initial_port
    i=1
    web_servers="server web$i $initial_ip:$initial_port check$n"
    more_web_servers=1;

    while [ $more_web_servers -eq 1 ]
    do
        echo "Would you like to add another web server?"
        select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
            case $yn in
                Yes )
                    echo "Please enter the IP address:"
                    read repeat_ip
                    echo "Please enter the port:"
                    read repeat_port;
                    ((i++))
                    web_servers+="    server web$i $repeat_ip:$repeat_port check$n";
                    break;;
                No ) more_web_servers=0; break;;
            esac
        done
    done

    echo "Do you want to turn HAProxy stats on?"
    select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
        case $yn in
            Yes ) stats=1; break;;
            No ) stats=0; break;;
        esac
    done
    if [[ $stats -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo "Enter the URL for stats:"
        read stats_uri
        echo "Please enter a user to access the stats page"
        echo "Please enter the Username:"
        read username
        echo "Please enter the Password:"
        read -s password
        users="stats auth $username:$password$n"
        more_users=1;

        while [ $more_users -eq 1 ]
        do
            echo "Would you like to add another user?"
            select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
                case $yn in
                    Yes )
                        echo "Please enter the Username:"
                        read username
                        echo "Please enter the Password:"
                        read -s password
                        users+="    stats auth $username:$password$n"
                        break;;
                    No ) more_users=0; break;;
                esac
            done
        done

        stats_text="stats enable
    stats uri $stats_uri
    stats realm Strictly\ Private
    $users"
    fi

    echo "global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 notice
    maxconn 2000
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    timeout connect  5000
    timeout client  10000
    timeout server  10000
listen web
    bind 0.0.0.0:80
    timeout connect  5000
    timeout client  10000
    timeout server  10000
    mode http
    $stats_text
    balance roundrobin
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    $web_servers $n" > "/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg"
    service haproxy restart
}

# web / cron
web (){
    cron_dir="$DIR/dist/cron";
    cron_content="#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/node $cron_dir";
    echo "Please enter the Redis Master IP:"
    read redis_master_ip
    echo "Please enter the Redis Master Auth password:"
    read -s redis_master_password
    echo "Please enter the HAProxy IP address:"
    read HAProxy_IP
    echo "{
    \"redis\": {
        \"current_environment\": \"prod\",
        \"environments\": {
            \"prod\": {
                \"host\": \"$redis_master_ip\",
                \"port\": \"6379\",
                \"password\": \"$redis_master_password\"
            }
        }
    },
    \"haproxy\": {
        \"IP\": \"$HAProxy_IP\"
    }
}" > "$DIR/web.config.json"
    npm install -g webpack gulp > /dev/null 2 >&1
    npm install > /dev/null 2 >&1
    echo "Before continuing, we need to build the solution.
Have you done this, or would you like to now? (yes or no)"
    select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
        case $yn in
            Yes ) npm run install; break;;
            No ) break;;
        esac
    done


    if [ -f "$cron_dir/posts.js" ]
    then
        echo "30 * * * *  $cron_content/posts.js > $DIR/posts.log" >> /etc/crontab
        echo "Posts CRON job added."
    fi
    if [ -f "$cron_dir/sites.js" ]
    then
        echo "0 23 * * * $cron_content/sites.js > $DIR/sites.log" >> /etc/crontab
        echo "Sites CRON job added."
    fi

    echo "start on runlevel [2345]
    start on filesystem
exec $DIR/node_modules/.bin/forever start $DIR/dist/web/index.js -o $DIR/out.log" > "/etc/init/web.conf"
    service web start
}

echo "StackNews setup script
-----------
Is this a Redis server, HAProxy server or web/cron server?"

select option in "Redis" "Web" "HAProxy"; do
    case $option in
        Redis ) redis; break;;
        Web ) web; break;;
        HAProxy ) haproxy; break;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 2):

#### shellcheck it!

There is this wonderful site called [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/#) that tells you all kinds of common mistakes.

#### The newline in a string

> ```
> n="
> "
> ```

`n` is an unusual name for something that's a newline. How about `newline`?

Here's another writing style that you might like:

```
n=$'\n'
```

For more details on this syntax, search for `\$'` in `man bash`.

#### Embedding variables in a string

The linebreak is odd in the middle of the string,
especially considering the `$n` variable that you have:

> ```
>         slave_text="slaveof $master_ip 6379
> masterauth $master_password $n"
> ```

I'm wondering if you didn't use `$n` because you were not sure how to make it work. Here are some equivalent ways to write the statement on a single line:

```
        slave_text="slaveof $master_ip 6379${n}masterauth $master_password $n"
        slave_text="slaveof $master_ip 6379$n""masterauth $master_password $n"
```

#### Embedding variables in text

This is very tedious, as you had to escape all the `"`:

> ```
> echo "{
>     \"redis\": {
>         \"current_environment\": \"prod\",
>         \"environments\": {
>             \"prod\": {
>                 \"host\": \"$redis_master_ip\",
>                 \"port\": \"6379\",
>                 \"password\": \"$redis_master_password\"
>             }
>         }
>     },
>     \"haproxy\": {
>         \"IP\": \"$HAProxy_IP\"
>     }
> }" > "$DIR/web.config.json"
> ```

A simpler approach would have been to enclose in single quotes instead,
and break out of it in front of variables, like this:

```
echo '{
    "redis": {
        "current_environment": "prod",
        "environments": {
            "prod": {
                "host": "'$redis_master_ip'",
                "port": "6379",
                "password": "'$redis_master_password'"
            }
        }
    },
    "haproxy": {
        "IP": "'$HAProxy_IP'"
    }
}' > "$DIR/web.config.json"
```

But an even better way is to use a here-string:

```
cat << EOF > "$DIR/web.config.json"
{
    "redis": {
        "current_environment": "prod",
        "environments": {
            "prod": {
                "host": "$redis_master_ip",
                "port": "6379",
                "password": "$redis_master_password"
            }
        }
    },
    "haproxy": {
        "IP": "$HAProxy_IP"
    }
}
EOF
```

#### Redirecting both `stdout` and `stderr`

Instead of this:

> ```
> npm install -g webpack gulp > /dev/null 2 >&1
> ```

A simpler way to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` is this:

```
npm install -g webpack gulp &> /dev/null
```

#### The shebang

Don't forget to start your script with the correct shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

#### Inconsistent use of `[` and `[[`

In some places you use `[` and in others `[[`.
I think it will be slightly easier to read the script if you used a consistent writing style.
`[` is [considered obsolete](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete), `[[` is recommended.

#### Trailing `;`

A `;` at the end of a line is pointless (unless it's part of a `;;` in a `case` statement). I suggest to remove those.

#### Tedious `-eq`

The `-eq` operator is kind of tedious here:

> ```
> if [[ $slave -eq 1 ]]; then
> ```

A simple `=` would work just as well, so I recommend to write that way.

#### Writing style

This is a bit unusual:

> ```
> pass (){
> ```

A more common writing style is this:

```
pass() {
```